# Stripe Elements, input validation upon form submit

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a payment flow using the following react stripe elements.

I'm using the onChange prop to display real-time errors as the user types. I also want these errors to show when the user hits the submit button. For example, if they don't fill any of the fields out and they click submit the following errors would show. However, the only way I have found to do this is by calling stripe.createPaymentMethod() which takes a couple of seconds to return a response and feels sluggish. What exactly does the onChange prop use under the hood to validate the input field and how can I use it instead of createPaymentMethod()?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An easier solution I found was to use Stripe's `useElements` to create an elements object:

```
const elements = useElements();
```

Subsequently, you can use this to grab the element you are interested in and check it's `_invalid` and `_empty` properties.

```
const cardNumber = elements.getElement('cardNumber');

const isInvalid = cardNumber._invalid;
const isEmpty = cardNumber._empty;

const isValid = !(isEmpty || isInvalid);
```

Note: The input is **NOT** considered invalid when it is empty. Thus the usage of `||` over `&&`.

Not sure why there isn't an easier method, but hey.

Comment: Unless otherwise stated, the `_` prefix tells us these are private properties and not meant to be accessed, i.e. could change. Probably not a good idea to go to production accessing these.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `change` event on Stripe Elements and look for `event.error` on the `event` passed to your event handler to [handle input validation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/input_validation).

When a Stripe Element loses focus and the value it contains does not appear to be valid `event.error` will be populated and contain a `code`, `message`, and `type` which you can use to update the Element's appearance and display the `message` to the user.

For example, when you provide a partial card number and switch focus to another field `event.error` will contain the following:

```json
"error": {
  "code": "incomplete_number",
  "type": "validation_error",
  "message": "Your card number is incomplete."
},
```